# Can we reinstate the [aarch64] tag as a synonym of [arm64]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I definitely agree that it would be preferable to keep questions about 64-bit ARM under a single tag, and we've had both [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64) and [aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aarch64) pretty much from the start. However, on 12th of November, all existing questions on [aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aarch64) were edited and retagged to [arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm64).

However, since `aarch64` is what you get in your `uname` output, and it's the only term you'll find in the ARM Architecture Reference Manual, it is pretty guaranteed to keep reappearing.

So could we have it reinstated as a synonym?

(This still leaves us the issue of questions incorrectly tagged as [armv8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/armv8), but short of adding moderator approval for certain tags, I don't see a way to resolve that one.)

Comment: I've approved the synonym you originally proposed September last year... so this is in effect done... not quite sure what you're saying is going on with armv8 though?

Comment: @JonClements: many thanks for that. As for armv8, the problem is that it is quite commonly conflated with arm64/aarch64, which is incorrect. On average, questions created on armv* tags are mistagged, and really belong on the arm, thumb or arm64 tags.

Comment: Sounds like some clarification in the tag wikis could possibly be warranted then?